# How to resolve named instances from LightCore ServiceLocator?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Lately I'm playing around a bit with the IoC tool LightCore. Since the last version no named instances are allowed anymore nontheless the ServiceLocator pattern is supported(?).

One of the crucial functionalities I need from the ServiceLocator is the resolving of named instances. My first idea was to override the DoGetInstance method and implement my own code.

My last workaround was to get a instance by it's typename

```
_testInstanceKey = "My.Namespace.MyType, MyAssembly";
IMyType type = locator.GetInstance(typeof(IMyType), _testInstanceKey)

protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
{
    return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType)
             .Where(x => x.GetType() == Type.GetType(key,true,true))
             .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This works out but what do I need a ServiceLocator for if I hardwire my typename?!

Has anybody any suggestions how I could work around this half-baked ServiceLocator?

Comment: The Service Locator pattern is [by definition half-baked](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). If you can, move to the dependency injection pattern.

Comment: Sad but true and I know that blogpost from Mark Seemann. Unfortunately I can't move because it's a legacy app that uses the ServiceLocator.

Comment: You always can, but it does take time. It won't happen in a day, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by introducing a `IMyTypeFactory` interface and letting the application take a dependency on that interface:

```
// Factory interface:
public interface IMyTypeFactory
{
    IMyType GetByName(string name);
}

// Implementation in the composition root:
public class MyTypeFactory :
    Dictionary<string, Func<IRequestHandler>>, IMyTypeFactory
{
    public IMyType GetByName(string name) { return this[name](); }
}

// Registration
var factory = new MyTypeFactory
{
    { "foo", () => new MyType1() },
    { "bar", () => new MyType2() },
    { "boo", () => new MyType3() },
};

builder.Register<IMyTypeFactory>(c => factory);
```

As I said in the comments, try to move away from the use of the Service Locator anti-pattern. It will improve the testability and maintainability of your application. When using the dependency injection (DI) pattern, you don't call the container directly and there is no way to directly ask a named instance. When applying DI, you will have to change the way to configure the container or need to apply the right abstractions in your application (as shown with the `IMyTypeFactory`).

Comment: In general you're completely right. Probably I mis-worded: it's an app/framework which uses internally a ServiceLocator but I can't change that code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change the way the framework calls the locator and assuming the framework uses the Common Service Locator is used as interface between your container and itself, you can add this functionality to a custom `IServiceLocator` implementation:

```
// This adapter wraps the CSL LightCoreAdapter of LightCore itself.
public class LightCoreServiceLocatorAdapter : IServiceLocator
{
    private readonly LightCoreAdapter container;

    public LightCoreServiceLocatorAdapter(IContainer container)
    {
        // You need a reference to LightCore.CommonServiceLocator.dll.
        this.container = new LightCoreAdapter(container);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TService> GetAllInstances<TService>()
    {
        return this.container.GetAllInstances<TService>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }

    public TService GetInstance<TService>(string key)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            return this.container.GetInstance<TService>(null);
        }
        else
        {
           // This is custom logic
           this.container.GetInstance<INamedFactory<TService>>().GetByKey(key);
        }
    }

    public TService GetInstance<TService>()
    {
        return this.container.GetInstance<TService>();
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            return this.container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }
        else
        {
            // This is custom logic
            var facType = typeof(INamedFactory<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType);
            var factory = (INamedFactory)this.container.GetInstance(facType);
            return factory.GetByKey(key);
        }
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    object IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        ((IServiceProvider)this.container).GetService(serviceType);
    }
}
```

This class uses the following two custom interfaces:

```
public interface INamedFactory
{
    object GetByKey(string key);
}

public interface INamedFactory<T> : INamedFactory
{
    T GetByKey(string key);
}
```

Using this custom `LightCoreServiceLocatorAdapter` and these two custom interfaces, you can create custom factories, such as this generic one:

```
public sealed class NamedDelegateFactory<T> : INamedFactory<T>
{
    private readonly Func<string, T> factory;

    public NamedDelegateFactory(Func<string, T> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public T GetByKey(string key)
    {
        return this.factory(key);
    }

    object INamedFactory.GetByKey(string key)
    {
        return this.factory(key);
    }
}
```

Which can be registered in the container as follows:

```
var factory = new NamedDelegateFactory<IMyType>(key =>
{
    if (key == "Cool") return new MyType1();
    else return new MyType2();
});

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register<INamedFactory<IMyType>>(c => factory);
```

Next, a `LightCoreServiceLocatorAdapter` can be created as follows:

```
var adapter = new LightCoreServiceLocatorAdapter(builder.Build());

Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator
    .SetLocatorProvider(() => adapter);
```

You can register all named instances using the `INamedFactory<T>` interface and use the `NamedDelegateFactory<T>` wrapped with a delegate or implement a custom type that implements `INamedFactory<T>`.